# Add system utility for xfce desktop environment

Tags: 18.04, xfce, customization

I am using xfce 4 in system, i.e I have just used this command to install xfce no other packages installed
(`sudo apt install xfce4`) https://xfce.org/
Unlike ubuntu it does not have wifi settings bluetooth settings
system about settings etc.

I am not much sure how to add these settings in it if their any plugin available.

Any idea how to add such basic utility to xfce to work in it efficiently ?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you have installed?  XFCE as used by Xubuntu includes those functions, but you've not specified how much of XFCE you have installed; refer to https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/xubuntu-desktop for all that is provided with Xubuntu (on-top of the Ubuntu base consistent with all Ubuntu *bionic* systems).  Also XFCE 4 tells us nothing with 4.0 being released in 2003 which was long ago, through to the modern 4.16 being the most *up-to-date*, so please be specific.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment i have updated the question

Comment: If you want to do it *efficiently* (in relation to what? the most efficient command would have been install `xubuntu-desktop` which is a single (large) meta package that grabs anything.. but efficient in relation to what???) adjust for what you installed (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/xfce4) versus what I provided in prior comment... I see two packages you'll need at minimum, but I'm not sure how you're classifying *efficient* (size of download?, size of install post-install?, size of command?, size of updates?, run-time considerations? etc...)